What would the ground be like if the sun is at ground level on an infinite plane?
The world is an infinite plane. There are geographical features here and there, but overall it's flat. The sun is at the center of the universe, its center aligned with the plane. This means half the sun is below ground-level.
What would the ground be like? I assume there would be a massive solar-system-scale ocean of lava, but are there other consequences I'm not considering?

How thick is the infinite plane?  Is there any gravity or equivalent force and if so, what direction does it act in?  Also, do you mean "infinite" literally?  If so, only a tiny fraction of the plane will be within a few light hours of the sun where its presence is relevant, the majority will be light hours or light years away where the sun's existence will diminish from irrelevant to undetectable.

What kind of answer are you looking for? It sounds like the star bisects a physical plane. Everything around it for a considerable distance is a blazing hot plasma. After that it's a blazing hot liquid. After that it's a blazing hot solid. Is it orbiting a center? Then it's digging a trough. Is it the center? How close are the observers? On an infinite plane they can be so far away that the sun appears to be a luminous dot barely illuminating the mostly shadowed and quite frozen area. Can you give is an image of the relationship? Lot of missing data here.

As others pointer out this cannot be answered without further information.

"The world is an infinite plane." – That sentence alone is incompatible with the concept of gravity. (If at every point in the plain "down" is perpendicular to the plain, the vector of gravity does not point towards a common center.) So what is a "Sun" in that context? Why would it form a ball of fire without gravity to hold it together? You are free to invent your own set of rules. Why not dispense also with radiation that follows the principle of conservation of energy? Then every point in the plain could receive the same amount of light and heat from the sun, regardless of distance.

Sounds like an Alderson disk. It's definitely livable, but only within a range of distance from the sun, so the habitable area isn't infinite (but still much greater than a planet).

@ccprog a infinite plane with uniform density would in fact exert gravity perpendicular to itself, what is the problem with that?

Even if the plane starts without an hole in the middle, the sun will eat its own through the plane. And far enough away will simply be so incredibly cold that whatever atmosphere you have is frozen solid, rendering the infinite size useless. (unless the plane got an infinite wide, magically sustained, planetary core too). I do wonder if there are other stars in this concept, all on the same plane.

Setting up such a world requires magic or equivalent technologies, so lets just not bother too much with mere physics and stability issues. For example, lets ignore gravity for the sake of argument, otherwise your infinite plane will just collapse sooner or later.
A main feature of such a setup would be that most of the world would be dark and cold, just like deep space. Depending on the size and temperature of your sun, you would get some maybe habitable zone from a heat perspective.
The innermost ring, close to the sun would be plasma. Unless you have magic measures in place to keep it where it is, it will move around and cause a mess (or given enough time, leave a hole around the sun). You should decide if your sun has solar winds, that would blow the plasma outwards. So in the end, you will have a gaseous hole in your disk, until you reach some substance that stays in a non plasma/gas state at the given temperature.
Then you get liquids. Also affected by solar winds. So it will move outward. Depending on your disks composition, you might get currents, when the outward flow hits the solidified lava in a zone thats too cold to stay liquid. There you might get turbulences, violent winds and other hellish features.
After that ring, you get some stable ground. Thats about the orbit of Mercury, if you scale things for a G type star like our sun. Too hot mostly, further out temperatures would improve. Might even be habitable, if you handwave some atmosphere. It would be huge, just look at some calculations for ringworlds, as you basically created something similar. You can more or less just take the usual habitable zones depending on the star class.
This also means that living beings (unless talking about surviving 800°C and more) have basically zero chances to see your lava ocean, as it would be too far away.
Further out, it would be cold, icy, and dark into infinity.

I'm not sure you would see the "usual habitable zones" - since the sun is perpetually low on the horizon (and you only see half of it), the light received per unit area would be substantially less than what you'd get on a planet at the same distance. So the habitable zone would be closer than you'd expect for a given star.

+1 No need for magic or technology. Just invent a whole new physics!

@Aetol: The light you get is the same, thats just a square law with distance. But your unit area that is able to absorb is smaller if you have just a flat disk. You can compensate a little by adding an atmosphere somehow, to add additional absorbing area. But you also get some heat transfer via conduction inside the disk, which would be more efficient than radiation alone. So with the level of handwaving needed to make it work, one can just postulate it balances out.

@elemtilas Tends to be harder to do plausible, consistent physics than adding some handwavy magic. Like getting a consistent set of the six numbers mentioned by Martin Rees (https://explainingscience.org/martin-rees-just-six-numbers/ ). But can be a fun mathematical exercise.

Utter destruction
The sun is hot[citation needed]. This alone is enough to doom your world in unimaginable huge distances. Let's look at one as an example. Wind.
A radiator at home displays the principle very well. Air is heated and expands. Lighter than the air around it, it flows up. The cooler air close to the ground moves in to 'replace' the air now going up. This causes a domino effect, where eventually a circle of air is produced. You barely notice it in most cases, but it's there.
This simple principle is cause of wind on Earth. Unequal heating of the air causes some to rise, some to fall, and move from high pressure to low pressure areas. Even slight differences can make a big impact on the speed of the wind. There is one more place where we can see this in fast action. A nuclear bomb. Though initially the shock wave pushes things outwards, the mushroom cloud is a result of super hot particles being expelled at high speed at the top and new particles rushing in from below to fill the lower pressure. There is also the metal sounding phenomenon of a fire storm, where a fire becomes so hot it'll generate wind towards it, supplying it with even more oxygen.
You have the sun putting out heat into the atmosphere. This is a continuous nuclear explosion of epic proportions. Without doing the math I can tell you that an area of many billions of kilometres is sucked into the sun just because of pressure difference. We're ignoring the gravity here. The recent hurricane winds in Florida are laughably small in comparison.
You might think it'll be no problem. At one point on an infinite plane the winds will have died down enough to live. While this is true, the light won't reach that far. The light will be absorbed by the atmosphere long before it reaches that place, making it too dark for any larger form of complex life to survive.
This is but a single problem, where there must be a huge amount. Even something like sound. If the Sun could transfer it's sound through space as if in atmosphere it would still be between 120 and 130 decibels, equivalent to standing right next to a jet engine or a continuous close proximity gun shot. The particles might be heavily radioactive with far reaching consequences. If you want anything close to normal life flourishing, you'll need a lot of suspension of disbelief.

TL;DR: some kind of interesting things happen, but there won't be any atmosphere.
I'll make the following assumptions for the sake of being able to answer. Feel free to edit the question if they're wrong, I don't mind this answer being invalidated. (Others might feel differently.)

the "sun" is a sphere of the same size, surface temperature and total energy output as our sun

however, it is not a ball of plasma but an indestructible solid sphere (otherwise it would just spread out across the infinite plane and stop being a big glowing ball)

the density of the sun is about the same as that of the ground, so it's considerably heavier than the real sun (otherwise it would rise until its weight equalled its buoyancy, so its centre wouldn't be aligned with the plane)

the force of gravity doesn't follow Newton's or Einstein's laws, it just points downwards everywhere at 9.8g.

aside from this, the laws of physics are the same as our world, and the material composition of the plane are the same as the Earth's mantle, crust and atmosphere.

there is a source of heat from deep below the plane, independently of the sun, so that the cold parts of the plane have some form of plate tectonics.


The second assumption is wildly unrealistic in, since no substance could hold a spherical shape under the forces this sun is subjected to, but then again we're talking about a world with an infinite plane, so I think I'm ok saying that this part is done by magic.
One thing we have to consider is, what would you find in this world if you could dig 700,000km deep? That's how deep the sun goes into the ground. For comparison, the core of the Earth is about 6,000km deep. Pressure increases linearly with depth${}^*$, so that means the pressure at 700,000km will be more than a thousand times greater than the core of the Earth. That's a lot more than the core of Jupiter but a lot less than a neutron star, and I don't really know what matter will be like at those pressures. I'm assuming it's similar enough to rock that we can treat it as rock.
Let's first think about what will happen far away from the sun. These parts of the plane will be much like the Earth would be without the sun. That means very, very cold, easily cold enough for the atmosphere to freeze. That means they're covered in a mix of water ice and frozen gases, and there's a vacuum above them. (That will become an issue later.) There will also be volcanic activity though (assuming a source of heat), so there will be liquid water and hydrothermal vents in places, mostly deep under ground, giving life a chance to hang on.
What happens closer to the sun? We're assuming the sun has the same surface temperature as the real sun, which is about $6000\rm^o\, C$. This is not hot enough to turn most matter into plasma, but it is hot enough to turn just about anything in the crust into a gas. This only applies to matter that's touching the sun near the surface though - once you get deep enough the pressure will prevent boiling. 6000 degrees is coincidentally also the temperature of the core of the Earth, so for the first few thousand miles of depth the sun will be surrounded by liquid molten rock. Deeper than that it will be solid again due to the pressure, like the Earth's solid iron core. (On large enough spatiotemporal scales all solids behave like fluids, so the sun will still float in it rather than sitting on top.)
So the area immediately surrounding the sun will be a roiling, boiling ocean of molten rock and iron. Since it's at the same temperature as the sun it will shine as brightly as the sun.
We're assuming a total heat output comparable to the real sun, which is ridiculously huge, so we should expect a geographically huge area surrounding the sun to heat up to thousands of degrees. We can get a rough idea of the size of this area by noting that, under our assumptions, the amount of heat radiating into space from the heated area needs to equal the amount of heat radiating into space from the exposed top half of the sun. Most of the heated area is likely to be substantially cooler than 6000 degrees (I'd guess at around the boiling point of iron, 2800 degrees, since boiling will cause it to rapidly lose heat). So the hot area will be substantially larger than the half the surface area of the sun. Which is ridiculously huge, especially when you consider how big the sun is compared to the Earth. However, it won't be that big compared to the size of the sun.
So we have to picture the sun as sitting in an unimaginably vast ocean of molten rock, the inner part of which is at the same temperature as the sun and is therefore violently boiling. The heat comes both from radiation from the sun and from conduction and convection from the matter that's in direct contact with it.
Above this molten rock is a vacuum, since all the air is frozen in the infinite icy wastes far away. But the boiling is producing huge amounts of gaseous rock. Most of this will condense and fall back on the molten rock as white hot rain, but perhaps some of it will reach further, landing on the solid ground. Volatiles will stay a gas for much longer and will be dispersed much further. This means that the molten rock will be slowly flowing inwards towards the sun to replace what's lost to boiling, kind of like a crazy molten rock version of a water cycle.
Now since we have molten rock in one place and frozen wastes in another, that means there's a point in between where the temperature is moderate. This area might also be quite large, given the absolutely ludicrous amounts of heat that we're talking about. It would certainly be much larger than the surface of the Earth. This area would be close enough to see the sun, and maybe it would be about the same distance from the sun as we are. (I don't really know.) However, the problem is that there won't be any atmosphere there, which puts a bit of a dampener on things. Without atmospheric pressure water can't stay liquid, it either freezes or boils, and so there won't be any water on the surface, although there can still be liquid water deep underground.
So if you're hoping for an Earth-like surface then you're out of luck, since there isn't any way to maintain a substantial atmosphere of any kind, let alone a breathable one. But it is a place where life could exist deep underground, and it's potentially a place where you could set up some kind of pressurised habitat, if you had a way to get there.
$^*$ actually pressure doesn't decrease linearly with depth on Earth, because gravity decreases as you get closer to the core. That doesn't happen on this infinite plane, so the pressure at any given depth will be greater than it is on Earth. But this doesn't greatly affect any of my estimates.

I think some assumptions are not needed. If you keep Newton's laws, the sun is massive enough to hold itself together without having to make it magically indestructible, and the rest of your answer still works.

@spectras the problem is that the sun will not only attract its own matter but also all the matter surrounding it. Any parts of the plane that are slightly denser than other parts will do the same, and so the whole thing will rapidly break up and turn into a bunch of black holes.
